# Add all folder items into archive using c#

Tags: c#

I want to add(and overwrite) all files including other folders that are in single folder.
Example:
In archive **zip.zip**:

```
work.docx             
1.txt                  
Photos          
 |_ocean.png          
 |_horse.png
```

After **adding** files & folder from another folder it would be like:

```
work.docx             
1.txt      
code.cs            
Photos          
 |_ocean.png
 |_horse.png
Program
 |_program.exe
 |_config.txt
```

I tried to do that with Ionic's zip library:

```
Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zf = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(@"C:\\zip.zip");
zf.UpdateDirectory(@"C:\\Program");
zf.Save();
```

It works, but it **doesn't overwrite files.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.5 then you can use

> System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive

It allows a single step compression.

```
 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@”C:\zip”, @”C:\zip.zip”);
```

To update it you can use ZipArchiveMode.Update

Comment: Will it overwrite?

Comment: You can use ZipArchiveMode.Update

Comment: Example, please?